# R apply advanced function on rownames

Tags: r, apply

at first, I would think that the following question is absolutely easy and I'm just not able to google or interpret it correctly, but if it is so, please show me a link, I will follow it.

I put in a minimal example of my current problem, but I'm interested in this issue in general.

```
dataset <- matrix(runif(10*3), nrow=10, ncol=3)
rownames(dataset) <- letters[1:dim(dataset)[1]]

betas <- matrix(0, nrow=dim(dataset)[1], ncol=2)
rownames(betas) <- letters[1:dim(dataset)[1]]
colnames(betas) <- c("sum", "2*sum")

for(name in rownames(betas)){
    res1 <- sum(dataset[name, ])
    res2 <- res1 *2 
    betas[name, ] <- c(res1, res2)
}
```

This works fine of course, but I have ~20000 rows, so it's taking too much time.

Can I use apply or one of its family to replace the loop?

**Edit:**
I somewhere lost the last codesection where I commented why I have to do it this way.
My real problem is the following, therefore I cant just make a sum and then multiply it later:

```
for(name in rownames(betas)){
    res1 <- coxph("amazing survival model calculations")
    res2 <- summary(res1) 
    betas[name, ] <- c(res1$coef, res2$coef[5])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an R one-liner to do the same thing:

```
cbind(betas, t(apply(dataset, 1, function(x) c('res1'=sum(x), 'res1*2'=sum(x)*2))))
```

Comment: This one works, thank you very much!
Just the cbind is not doing how you suppose I think, I used the rear, but with the cbind I get a matrix with 4 columns, in the first2 only zeros.

Answer (score 0):

`rowSums()` retains the `names` attribute of `data.frames` and `matrices`, so you can easily do this:

```
x <- rowSums(dataset)
cbind( "sum" = x , "sum*2"=x*2)
#        sum    sum*2        
#a 1.9457679 3.891536
#b 1.5798699 3.159740
#c 1.8086066 3.617213
#d 1.7802458 3.560492
#e 0.8076846 1.615369
#f 2.1001424 4.200285
#g 1.5129077 3.025815
#h 1.9098082 3.819616
#i 1.1109019 2.221804
#j 1.5256368 3.051274
```

Comment: I probably edited after you commented, I sadly do not ned the sums but a more complex thing with coxph-models, my code was just a minimalistic version of my problem :)
thank you nevertheless! :)